# Which SDK to use for Gear 2 Neo?

Tags: sdk, embedded, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

On the [developer.tizen.org](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tools/download) you can download an SDK called "Tizen 2.3 Rev3 SDK" and one named "Tizen SDK for Wearable 1.0.0".

When installing the first one you have the option to install a "Mobile-2.3" (which I guess is for smartphones) and a "Wearable-2.3" (which I thought is for e.g. smart watches like the Gear 2)

Now I'm wondering - when I definitively want to develop for a "wearable" device (Gear 2), which SDK should I use? What are the differences in general?

Is there a way to develop natively (C++) for a Gear 2 (Neo)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install first one basically it'll have for both mobile and wearable i.e if you have plans to work on both mobile and wearable. If you have storage constraints on your system then install second one which is only for wearable.

No, you cannot write native apps for Gear 2 neo. Only web apps are supported currently for wearables.

But yea for the new tizen wearable version 2.3.1, native apps will be supported. Recently (yesterday) tizen 2.3.1 preview was released.

Comment: Do you know how the versions are counted then? Shouldn't "Tizen SDK for Wearable 1.0.0" be called "Tizen 2.3 Rev3 SDK - wearable standalone"?

Comment: Wearable 1.0.0 is probably the version of wearable sdk version not the TIZEN OS version. When you create an app check the prefix in project name in tizen sdk project explorer, it'll show <projname>-wearable -2.3. Tizen 2.3 rev3 sdk shows the tizen OS version in its name.